# pagerjs -- recommended method of handling page refresh

Tags: javascript, pagerjs

What's the best approach to handling page-refresh given a stateful pagerjs app? I'm leaning towards having a sourceLoaded handler for every page validating the sanity of the model. If not passed, it navigates the user to the entry page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `guard`. See http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/navigation/guards in the demo.